# Is there a way to modify the MessageType in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I am interfacing to an existing Azure service bus application, that uses MassTransit to publish messages.

Due to not following the guidance here https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html#message-names message types are badly named.

I know I can use `[EntityName]` to override the topic naming convention, but I want to also override the message type.

At the moment, I have to create message types as below:

```
namespace SillyName.Messages;
public interface MyBadMessageType {}
```

I would like to name my message classes like this:

```
namespace OtherSystem.Messages;
public interface IUpdateUserMessage {}
```

Is there a way to override the default naming convention of MassTransit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the *messageType* element in the JSON envelope, that value cannot be changed without changing the actual message type itself (namespace, class, assembly).

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much. :-(